# Creating a Text File and Writing to it In objective c OS X El Capitan

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have been working with updating my app for El Capitan throughout the entire beta, but cannot solve this problem. I am not an advanced user so this may be simple for you to point me in the correct direction.

My app uses a preferences file, and it creates it and writes to it if it does not already exist. However, in El Capitan it will crash the app if the preferences file does not exist. So I had to modify my installer to create a blank file during the installation process so I could write to it later.

After hours of researching, I believe it has to do with the encoding of the file, because I can't just create a pref.txt file and it work, it has to be the same encoding of pref file as the previous version my app would create. I have no idea how to find out what encoding that is, but I want my app to create and edit files using utf-8 for compatibility. Here is an example of my code now, and I don't know what property to use to tell xcode to use my default text document encoding.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
-(void) loadPreferences{

myPath = @"~/myApp/pref.txt";
myPath = [myPath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

enc = NULL;
error = NULL;

NSString *dataToWrite = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:myPath usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc error:error];
NSArray *dataFromFile = [content componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
if([lengthOfFile count] == 2){
    [firstField setStringValue:lines[0]];
    [secondField setStringValue:lines[1]];
}else{
    [self createPrefFile:self];
}
```

All that "[createPrefFile:self]" does is re-run this method, it worked with creating the file and then running through it again to see that it was created as a one time loop through. (Not ideal I know)

Comment: Whether it's already sandboxed or not, that's not a good location where to store your application file.

Comment: Yeah, the location was changed for simplicity and easier to read, as it is in a nested folder in the Application Support folder.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using NSUserDefaults instead, way more efficient